# How to "redirect" from main page in Prestashop to specific product page?

Tags: url-rewriting, prestashop, redirect

What I want is "simply" to auto-direct anyone who visits the main landing page of my Prestashop site, e.g.: 'http://www.myprestashop.com' to a specific product page, e.g.: 'http://www.myprestashop.com/music-ipods/1-ipod-nano.html'

I have tried various combinations of codes in the .htaccess, without any luck, though I have to admit that URL-re-writing/modification is not my strongest suit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your .htaccess

Redirect 301 / http://www.myprestashop.com/music-ipods/1-ipod-nano.html